# Cheat Sheets for System Administrators?

Tags: untagged

I'd like to start a collection of good, free **cheat sheet** resources for system administrators. Please add your favorite ones. From the [Wikipedia "cheat sheet" article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_sheet):

> In more general usage, a "cheat sheet"
>   is any short (one or two page)
>   reference to terms, commands, or
>   symbols where the user is expected to
>   understand the use of such terms etc
>   but not necessarily to have memorized
>   all of them.

Answer (score 84):

I add my own favorite: **[Cheat Sheets on PacketLife.com](http://packetlife.net/library/cheat-sheets/)** has some very nice ones on network technology topics.

> Cheat sheets are in PDF format. You
>   are welcome to use and redistribute
>   them as you please, so long as they
>   remain intact and unmodified.

Currently there are six categories:

- *Protocols:* BGP, EIGRP, First Hop Redundancy, IEEE 802.11 Wireless, IEEE 802.1X, IPsec, IPv4 Multicast, IPv6, IS-IS, OSPF, Spanning Tree
- *Applications:* tcpdump, Wireshark Display Filters
- *Reference:* Common Ports, IP Access Lists, Subnetting
- *Syntax:* Markdown, MediaWiki
- *Technologies:* MPLS, Quality of Service, VLANs
- *Miscellaneous:* Cisco IOS Versions, Physical Terminations

**Examples:** [Common Ports](http://packetlife.net/media/library/23/common-ports.pdf) and [IPv6](http://packetlife.net/media/library/8/IPv6.pdf) (links to PDF files)

[image: Common Ports Cheat Sheet (PDF)]

Comment: Oh, so THAT site is why wget has a --mirror function... Thanks!

Comment: You know you have all that info in /etc/services, right Ok no color but still, it's handy

Answer (score 36):

I wish to use this at some point... for now though, I'm a nano dork but thought it might be handy for some here:

### Printable (PDFs)

**QWERTY**:[**http://locobox.googlepages.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet-qwerty.pdf**](http://locobox.googlepages.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet-qwerty.pdf)
**Dvorak**:[**http://locobox.googlepages.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet-dvorak.pdf**](http://locobox.googlepages.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet-dvorak.pdf)

[alt text http://locobox.googlepages.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif](http://locobox.googlepages.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif)

Comment: a little frightened to ask, but do you have the qwerty?

Comment: The link is to the DVORAK but the image posted is for the QWERTY

Comment: Sorry about that... ok, I added a link for the QWERTY version (now, both are there).  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Hm. I think i prefer not to have to use a cheat sheet for my text editor.

Answer (score 26):

[Learning Vim the Pragmatic Way.](http://jrmiii.com/2009/03/06/learning-vim-the-pragmatic-way.html)

http://jrmiii.com/attachments/Vim.png

Answer (score 25):

[image: Map of the internet]

[Source](http://xkcd.com/195/)

Comment: I wonder what that looks like today.

Comment: That's pretty cool!

Comment: @Martijn Heemels: As of Feb 2011, it's much less interesting - no more green squares, IPv4 fully allocated.

Comment: I love the ~~~ wavey lines!

Answer (score 24):

### OpenSSH Quick Reference

- Author: [Jialong He](http://www.bigfoot.com/~jialong_he)
- [Download (PDF)](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/OpenSSH_quickref.pdf)

[image: OpenSSH Quick Reference PDF]

Answer (score 22):

[Protocol encapsulation chart from Wildpackets (PDF format)](http://users.lmi.net/canepa/subdir/encasulation_chart.pdf)

[image: Protocol encapsulation chart image]

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: rlogin and rsh but no ssh?  What is this, 1993?

Answer (score 15):

[VMware Infrastructure 3 Reference Card](http://www.vreference.com/vi3-card)

[AWK, NAWK, GAWK Cheat Sheet](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-nawk-and-gawk-cheat-sheet/)

[Rosetta Stone for UNIX](http://bhami.com/unix-rosetta.pdf)

Answer (score 15):

Google.com (I know - it's not a list with two-word commands, but it saves my behind every time).

Comment: had to give it a +1

Answer (score 11):

[**Computer Hardware Chart**](http://www.geekologie.com/image.php?path=/2009/07/22/computer-hardware-2.jpg) (Geekologie):

[image: Hardware Chart]

Comment: Geekologie is so much fun.  ;)

Comment: Link to original: http://sonic840.deviantart.com/art/Computer-hardware-poster-1-7-111402099

Answer (score 10):

A while ago I found this helpful [Linux/Unix Command Cheat Sheet](http://fosswire.com/post/2007/08/unixlinux-command-cheat-sheet/).

[image: Unix/Linux Command Reference]

Answer (score 9):

Nice Windows 2008 technology posters available here:

[**Windows Server 2008 Component Posters**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c2b9e44e-0bbd-47cb-bc09-b3d48be7f867&displaylang=en)

- Windows Server 2008 Feature Components
- Windows Server 2008 Active Directory Components

> These two posters, originally
>   published in the July 2007 issue of
>   TechNet Magazine, provide a strong
>   visual tool to aide in the
>   understanding of various features and
>   components of Windows Server 2008. One
>   poster focuses exclusively on powerful
>   new Active Directory technologies,
>   while the other provides a technical
>   look at a variety of new features
>   available in Windows Server 2008 (such
>   as Server Core, Network Access
>   Protection, and more).

[image: Windows Server 2008 PDF Posters]

Answer (score 9):

[PowerShell Quick Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=DF8ED469-9007-401C-85E7-46649A32D0E0&displaylang=en)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

And a list with cheat sheets for different languages, systems and so on.

http://www.cheat-sheets.org/

Comment: Am I happy to find this link!

Answer (score 8):

*[Windows 2003 Command Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778084(WS.10).aspx)* is more of a 50 lb manual than a cheat sheet, though if someone has something lightweight with the compressed syntax, that would rock...

Comment: I found one here [pdf warning !] http://www.sans.org/resources/sec560/windows_command_line_sheet_v1.pdf which is far from complete though... I also found this: http://www.ss64.com/nt/index.html Not really a cheat sheet, but better than a 50 lb manual ;-)

Comment: I find myself with a series of little paper slips with syntax for dsquery & such.  Maybe I'll get motivated and make my own admin-centric 2003 command cheat sheet.  ;)

Answer (score 8):

[**SQL Server Cheat Sheet**](https://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/sql-server-cheat-sheet/)

> The SQL Server cheat sheet is a
>   one-page A4 printable document,
>   designed to provide a quick reference
>   for SQL Server. A description of what
>   is on the cheat sheet follows, or if
>   you are impatient, you can go straight
>   to the full size SQL Server cheat
>   sheet.

- Data Types and Conversion
- Functions
- Creations

[image: SQL Server Data Types and Conversion]

Download link: [PDF file](https://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/download/sql-server-cheat-sheet-v1.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

Not free, but definitely worth mentioning.
[xkcd](http://xkcd.com) have a [wearable Linux cheat sheet](http://store.xkcd.com/xkcd/#LinuxCheatShirt).

[image: xkcd Linux cheat shirt]

Answer (score 6):

[Life's cheat sheet http://909sickle.com/s/lifes-cheat-sheet/lifes-cheat-sheet.png](http://909sickle.com/s/lifes-cheat-sheet/lifes-cheat-sheet.png)

[Source](http://909sickle.com/s/lifes-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: your math doesn't add up here. you are born -1000 then going the job route you get +1000. Unless I missed something or this is some new age math stuff I thought -1000 + 1000 = 0. And then you get taxed on the 1000 that you earned so you really have -1. Am I missing something.

Comment: I think you'll have to ask the author about this... Don't shoot the messenger ;-)

Comment: -1 (to the author) for spelling "marriage" incorrectly.

Answer (score 6):

[**Simple RAID Cheat Sheet**](http://www.hyperionreactor.net/blog/simple-raid-cheat-sheet)

I'm sure it's just because I don't mess with RAID that often, but when I do need it, this is immensely helpful.

Comment: The right link is: http://www.hyperionreactor.net/content/simple-raid-cheat-sheet

Comment: I edited the answer with the correct link.

Comment: It misses RAID-6, which is more and more common. And RAID-4, found in NetApp, DataDirect Networks and some other high-end products.

Comment: If you've got a cheat sheet that has those, I'll add it into my post.

Comment: The link appears to be broken again.

Answer (score 6):

- [Subversion SVN Cheat Sheet](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/misc/svn01/)
- [Larger set of computing topics](http://refcards.com/).

Answer (score 6):

[System Administrator Interview Cheat Sheet](http://mj12net.org/index.php/system-administrator-interview-cheat-sheet.html)

Answer (score 5):

This [regular expression cheat sheet in PDF format](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2/pdf/) has been pretty helpful in the past.

Answer (score 5):

[Unix Toolbox](http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.xhtml)

> This document is a collection of
>   Unix/Linux/BSD commands and tasks
>   which are useful for IT work or for
>   advanced users. This is a practical
>   guide with concise explanations,
>   however the reader is supposed to know
>   what s/he is doing.

Answer (score 4):

I enjoy keyboard shortcuts

**Windows:** http://www.intelliadmin.com/blog/2006/04/windows-keyboard-shortcuts-you-never.html

**VI:** http://www.keyxl.com/aaab462/105/VIM-Text-Editor-keyboard-shortcuts.htm

Cheatsheet

**Perl** http://juerd.nl/site.plp/perlcheat

Answer (score 4):

[Useful Vim commands](http://web.mit.edu/merolish/Public/vi-back.pdf) (PDF).

Answer (score 4):

[Linux Unix Cheat Sheets](http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/115/linux-unix-cheat-sheets---the-ultimate-collection/)

[Ghantoos Memo](http://ghantoos.org/memo/)

[Command Line Fu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/browse)

[OpenBSD 101](http://www.openbsd101.com/)

Answer (score 4):

[**http://www.connectionstrings.com**](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

I use it all the time for system administrator and developer related tasks, especially when trying to make an applications talk to a database other than what it was originally designed for and the support isn't all that great.

Comment: Oh yes, I also use it when I have to deal with some exotic databases. Like Access ;-)

Comment: Heh.  Yeah, all my Access work is done out of pity.

Answer (score 3):

As an admin (and after) I find that I need to often create tools for the browser.

I'm not a designer (nor do I desire to be one), but I have found [VisiBone](http://www.visibone.com/) cheat sheets immensely helpful:

- [HTML tags](http://html-tags.info/)
- [JavaScript regular expressions](http://www.visibone.com/regular-expressions/)

Answer (score 3):

[Rewrite Rules Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/)

PECL Regex Cheat Sheet:
[image: PECL Cheat Sheet]

Answer (score 2):

I created a Vim cheatsheet in various formats a couple of years ago: [Vim Cheatsheet](http://tjl2.com/sysadmin/vim-cheat-sheet)

Answer (score 2):

Found [this whimpy list](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/0,,sid9_gci826135,00.html) of links to various sheets for various technologies...there's only, oh, I dunno, ***three dozen*** of these...

Answer (score 2):

**Apache 1.3 Quick Reference Card**

[image: Apache Cheat Sheet thumbnail]

Link: [**PDF file**](http://refcards.com/docs/forda/apache/apache-refcard-a4.pdf) (2 pages)

Answer (score 2):

Set Operations for Unix. some of the most useful stuff I've seen to date.  Not only it speeds things up greatly, but it educates you how to do things in a smarter way than the CS101 'solve it for one case, put it in a loop' strategies.

[Website](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell/) with explanations

Shorter version, for hanging on the cubewall: [DOWNLOAD](http://www.catonmat.net/download/setops.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

**Linux Command wallpaper**

[alt text http://www.letslearnlinux.com/suseblog/wallpaper/big/linux-wallpaper-for-beginners.jpg](http://www.letslearnlinux.com/suseblog/wallpaper/big/linux-wallpaper-for-beginners.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

[**DevCheatSheet.com**](http://devcheatsheet.com/) - *Huge* collection of cheat sheets and reference cards for developers (and admins)

Answer (score 1):

More for web development, but I just added the following excellent resource to my bookmarks this morning.

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/tools/cheat-sheets/front-end-web-developers-toolbox.html

All of my other favorites have already been mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Server 9i Quick Reference Guide**

Link: [PDF file](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/9iquickref.pdf) (0.9 MB)*

<sub>* It's not really a cheat sheet, there are 37 pages, but it is very compressed information.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Command-line Cheat Sheets](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/)

And with an [iPhone app](http://cheatapp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of good ones on [www.drp.co.za](http://www.drp.co.za)

Answer (score 1):

[WordPress Template/Theme Editing](http://ekinertac.com/?p=259)

Many sheets on many topics including [HTML, JavaScript, JSP, CSS, Delphi, Ada, C, C#, C++, etc. ad nauseam](http://www.digilife.be/quickreferences/quickrefs.htm) (a listing of sheets from many sources)

Also and perhaps most important for admins even if it's not really a single-page format: [Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html) which lists equivalent commands for AIX, A/UX, DG/UX, FreeBSD, HP-UX, IRIX, Linux, Mac OS X, NCR Unix, NetBSD, OpenBSD, Reliant, SCO OpenServer, Solaris, SunOS 4, Tru64, Ultrix and UNICOS

That last one was very useful when dealing with disks - I was looking for something like parted, not for "divvy" which is what SCO OpenServer uses.

Answer (score 1):

Blog Post: [PowerShell Cheat Sheet Redux - the PDF version](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/01/25/powershell-cheat-sheet-redux-the-pdf-version.aspx)

Two page cheat sheet for some common group of tasks

Answer (score 1):

I keep the Vi Reference Mug on my desk just in case I forget something.

Also, I saw a cheat sheet here for Subversion but not one for Git. Try [this one](http://mattonrails.com/files/Git.png).

Comment: Mentioned link is dead. Check here for more Git cheat sheets: http://zrusin.blogspot.com/2007/09/git-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 0):

[Exchange 2007 Management Shell Quick Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?FamilyID=01a441b9-4099-4c0f-b8e0-0831d4a2ca86&displaylang=en) - it's a start, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

- [**OpenSSL** Cheat Sheet](http://wiki.samat.org/CheatSheet/OpenSSL) (webpage)
- [**jQuery 1.4.2** Visual Cheat Sheet](http://woorkup.com/2010/06/13/jquery-1-4-2-visual-cheat-sheet/) (various formats)

[image: jQuery cheat sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Real World FIND usage:

The original page is gone (also linked from [Linux Today](http://www.linuxtoday.com/news/2009071502435PS)), but I found it again on web.archive.org.
http://web.archive.org/web/20090426000044/http://www.wagoneers.com/UNIX/FIND/find-usage.html

Whenever I had a question about unix find syntax or needed an example, I'd reference this.

```
find / -type f -name *.jpg  -exec cp {} . \;
find . -type f -size +10000 -exec ls -al {} \;
find . -atime +1 -type f -exec mv {} TMP \; # mv files older then 1 day to dir TMP
find . -name "-F" -exec rm {} \;   # a script error created a file called -F 
find . -exec grep -i "vds admin" {} \;
find . \! -name "*.Z" -exec compress -f {} \;
find . -type f \! -name "*.Z" \! -name ".comment" -print | tee -a /tmp/list
find . -name *.ini
find . -exec chmod 775 {} \;
find . -user xuser1 -exec chown -R user2 {} \;
find . -name ebtcom*
find . -name mkbook
find . -exec grep PW0 {} \;
find . -exec grep -i "pw0" {} \;
find . -atime +6
find . -atime +6 -exec ll | more
find . -atime +6 -exec ll | more \;
find . -atime +6 -exec ll \;
find . -atime +6 -exec ls \;
find . -atime +30 -exec ls \;
find . -atime +30 -exec ls \; | wc -l
find . -name auth*
find . -exec grep -i plotme10 {};
find . -exec grep -i plotme10 {} \;
find . -ls -exec grep 'PLOT_FORMAT 22' {} \;
find . -print -exec grep 'PLOT_FORMAT 22' {} \;
find . -print -exec grep 'PLOT_FORMAT' {} \;
find . -print -exec grep 'PLOT_FORMAT' {} \;
find ./machbook -exec chown 184 {} \;
find . \! -name '*.Z' -exec compress {} \;
find . \! -name "*.Z" -exec compress -f {} \;
find /raid/03c/ecn -xdev -type f -print
find /raid/03c/ecn -xdev -path -type f -print
find / -name .ssh* -print | tee -a ssh-stuff
find . -name "*font*"
find . -name hpmcad*
find . -name *fnt*
find . -name hp_mcad* -print
find . -grep Pld {} \;
find . -exec grep Pld {} \;
find . -exec grep Pld {} \;
find . -exec grep PENWIDTH {} \; | more
find . -name config.pro
find . -name config.pro
find /raid -type d ".local_sd_customize" -print
find /raid -type d -name ".local_sd_customize" -print
find /raid -type d -name ".local_sd_customize" -ok cp /raid/04d/MCAD-apps/I_Custom/SD_custom/site_sd_customize/user_filer_project_dirs {} \;
find /raid -type d -name ".local_sd_customize" -exec cp /raid/04d/MCAD-apps/I_Custom/SD_custom/site_sd_customize/user_filer_project_dirs {} \;
find . -name xeroxrelease
find . -exec grep xeroxrelease {} \;
find . -name xeroxrelease
find . -name xeroxrelease* -print 2>/dev/null
find . -name "*release*" 2>/dev/null
find / -name "*xerox*" 2>/dev/null
find . -exec grep -i xeroxrelease {} \;
find . -print -exec grep -i xeroxrelease {} \;
find . -print -exec grep -i xeroxrelease {} \; > xeroxrel.lis
find . -exec grep -i xeroxrel {} \;
find . -print -exec grep -i xeroxrel {} \;
find . -print -exec grep -i xeroxrel {} \; | more
find /raid/03c/inwork -xdev -type f -print >> /raid/04d/user_scripts/prt_list.tmp
find . -exec grep '31.53' {} \;
find . -ls -exec grep "31/.53" {} \; > this.lis
find . -print -exec grep "31/.53" {} \; > this.lis
find . -print -exec grep 31.53 {} \; > this.lis
find . -exec grep -i pen {} /;
find . -exec grep -i pen {} \;
find . -print -exec grep -i pen {} \; | more
find . -exec grep -i pen {} \;
find . -atime +6 -exec ll | more \;
find . -atime +6 -exec ll \;
find . -atime +6 -exec ls \;
find . -atime +30 -exec ls \;
find . -atime +30 -exec ls \; | wc -l
find . \! -name '*.Z' -exec compress -f {} \;
find . -name 'cache*' -depth -exec rm {} \;
find . -name 'cache*' -depth -print | tee -a /tmp/cachefiles
find . -name 'cache[0-9][0-9]*' -depth -print | tee -a /tmp/cachefiles
find . -name 'hp_catfile' 'hp_catlock' -depth -print | tee -a /tmp/hp.cats
find . -name 'hp_catfile' -name 'hp_catlock' -depth -print | tee -a /tmp/hp.cats
find . -name 'hp_cat*' -depth -print | tee -a /tmp/hp.cats
find . -name 'hp_cat[fl]*' -depth -print | tee -a /tmp/hp.cats
find /raid -name 'hp_cat[fl]*' -depth -print
find . \! -name '*.Z' -exec compress -f {} \;
find . -name '*' -exec compress -f {} \;
find . -xdev -name "wshp1*" -print
find . -xdev -name "wagoneer*" -print
find . -name "xcmd" -depth -print
find /usr/contrib/src -name "xcmd" -depth -print
find /raid -type d -name ".local_sd_customize" -exec ls {} \; 
find /raid -type d -name ".local_sd_customize" \
   -exec cp /raid/04d/MCAD-apps/I_Custom/SD_custom/site_sd_customize/user_filer_project_dirs {} \;
```